# Cross-Browser Extensions API?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

There are tools for developing [cross-platform browser plugins](http://www.firebreath.org).

Are there any similar tools or APIs for browser extensions (i.e. toolbars, or filter systems like AdBlock)?

Comment: Your title and examples refer to extensions, but in your question you refer to plugins and a plugin framework. I belive you want extenstions. Please see: http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference and: firebreath.org for cross-browser plugin frameworks

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what is the difference between (add here anything extension you like) and AdBlock? Isn't AdBlock jus also an extension (or plugin if you want)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, but unfortunately each one has significant drawbacks.

- [Kynetx](http://kynetx.com) <s>supports IE, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, but extensions are dependent on the Kynetx extension to work. In addition, Kynetx apps are built using an odd, proprietary [Kynetx Rules Language](https://github.com/kre/Kinetic-Rules-Engine/). There is no cost to use the Kynetx platform</s>. UPDATE: Kynetx has shut down
- [WebMynd](http://webmynd.com) <s>supports IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and is in private beta. From what I have been able to determine, WebMynd is a very small San Francisco-based startup that is still getting off the ground. Their library is standalone and provides a Javascript API, and they use a monthly billing model</s>. UPDATE: company pivoted, now for mobile, trigger.io
- [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) <s>supports IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Recently out of beta (as of June 2012), Crossrider is free and offers a jQuery-based development experience. Publishing methods for your extensions include an embeddable website widget, download links, and a customized windows installer. However, CrossRider does not allow you to self-host your plugin files</s>. UPDATE: As of 27.09.2016, CrossRider is terminated and it will be available only until 27.10.2016.
- [KangoExtensions](http://kangoextensions.com/) <s>supports IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. Seems very new and bleeding edge, like Crossrider, also looks promising.</s> UPDATE: No updates in over two years.

IE and Firefox seem to be the [hardest to develop for](http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2011/01/29/writing-browser-extensions/), although [Mozilla JetPack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/) aims to greatly simplify Firefox extension development.

Comment: Great post Jonathan. One little comment regarding Crossrider. [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) is a white-label framework and as such, extensions can be downloaded from your own site. Crossrider provides an embed widget that detects the user's browsers and download their platform's exntesion file. You can also use the direct download links to .crx .xpi and .exe files (chrome/ff/ie). You can also serve those extension files from your own servers. One last note: Safari support is coming soon.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of WebMynd. We've now launched in public beta with tutorial and API documentation here: http://docs.webmynd.com/en/latest/index.html

Comment: KangoExtensions is an option only if you're open-source or willing to spend a couple of thousand $$

Comment: What are the drawbacks of CrossRider?

Comment: The drawbacks of Crossrider appear to be less than when I originally wrote the post, and they are worth a try. Their main drawback at this point is that they are a proprietary layer of technology in your application, which would cause problems if you need to be able to dynamically compile extension packages (as my application required), or if the company should go belly-up (they are a startup, after all). I would be more comfortable if they provided their libraries and compilation tools open source.

Comment: It appears that WebMynd has done a pivot, and is now focusing on Cross-platform Mobile Development with PhoneGap, Sencha, and Appcelerator as their competitors.

Comment: I wonder what is the current state? http://www.quora.com/What-cross-browser-extension-framework-is-good-to-use-when-developing-a-Gmail-plugin Is there a single, reliable, supported platform with community etc...?

Comment: About Kango, they only provide Chrome / Safari / FF support on "free" version, for IE support, you must pay $2290 (just asked).

Comment: ***This answer is probably getting obsolete*** as the [WebExtensions API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions) is gaining popularity and acceptance. If you have an idea for an extension, it should most probably be written in WebExtensions API.

Comment: I've used Kango in the past, but as of 2021 it appears all download links and source code have been disabled/deleted.  Perhaps a security compromise?

Answer (score 19):

There is also very young framework for cross-browser development called BabelExt, from the author of Reddit Enhancement Suite. I like that it builds restartless Jetpacks for Firefox.

See more on github, https://github.com/honestbleeps/BabelExt

Comment: Great find Tim — it is a great example of building extensions from scratch as well!

Comment: Update: "BabelExt is essentially obsolete at this point, as Firefox now supports WebExtensions, Opera is now Chromium-based, and even Microsoft Edge has adopted Chrome's format."

Answer (score 18):

Mozilla has recently introduced [WebExtensions API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions). For now it's actually almost a copy of Chrome Extension API (but some APIs aren't implemented yet). It has been introduced just a few days ago so it still has a lot of problems and unsupported APIs. But if you're interested in writing extensions for Chrome, Opera and Firefox you should pay attention to the state of WebExtensions API.

**UPD 27.10.16.** There is a page [Are-we-WebExtensions-Yet](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/) which summarises the current state of WebExtensions. By their current estimate 44.99% extensions from Chrome store should work in Firefox.

Comment: WebExtensions are now supported by Opera and Edge too (by a varying degree).

Answer (score -1):

[ExtensionMaker](http://extensionmaker.com) is another one project related to cross browser extensions development. It is not a real framework. It is kinda IDE that allows you to design basic extensions.

Of course, it is not suitable for a serious projects. But I like the idea.

Full featured version is available for free. There is just small limitations on the way of using generated extensions.