# cross-browser extension development alternatives

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox-addon, safari-extension, browser-extension

I would like to develop a `browser extension` for all major browsers. From what I've read this can be quite painful, particularly for `IE`.

Before starting with the project, I would like to know what are my basic alternatives. I can think of two:

1. Develop an extension independently for each browser
2. Hire someone to develop the extension for me

Are there any other options?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913123/cross-browser-extensions-api

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two more alternatives:

- you can use a cross-browser extension development framework, like the ones described [here](http://hightechstartups.blogspot.com/2012/05/developing-browser-extensions-fast-way.html)
- minimize the amount of code that necessarily has to run in the extension because it requires extended privileges, for instance access to special browser functionality. Put the rest of the code in a JavaScript file and make the extension inject it in every page. You can write this JS once and reuse it for every browser (if you are careful with JS cross-browser issues, or use [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)). You could even move the UI parts to this JS file and let the toolbar appear **inside** of the web page instead of **on** the browser window, just like [Browseye](http://www.browseye.com/) and [Meebo](https://www.meebo.com/download) have done.

[Here](http://hightechstartups.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/different-way-of-developing-browser.html) you can find a list of the pros and cons of the different alternatives.

Hiring somebody should be the last option. Be careful with intellectual property issues and disputes over the ownership of the extension code.

Answer (score 12):

You should definitely check out the Crossrider [cross-browser development framework](http://crossrider.com)

With their platform you can:

1. Develop cross-browser extensions with only javascript code and one API
2. Supports Chrome, Firefox, Safari and most importantly Internet Explorer!
3. Crossrider has an online IDE where you can develop extensions on the fly and with no need to download an SDK (you can however develop locally on your machine if you wish)
4. Fully customised Windows Installer which can be install on all browser from one EXE and can also be defined as a SILENT installer.
5. Hosted installation pages and Installation Widget if you wish to install user to your own website
6. 24/7 Support!

And much much more..

Comment: I used Crossrider for a while and I found that it lacked some of the most basic capabilities.  I went to Kango instead and I love it.

Comment: the thing is lot of antivirus software picks up crossrider as adware and blocks it

Answer (score 10):

Try [Kango](http://kangoextensions.com/) - cross-browser extension framework.

Comment: Kango is a great choice for extensions development. I am using it and i am glad of it :) RECOMMENDED.

Comment: Kango is at $2200 plus one year support for the commercial license... NB: the free option, i.e. if you are non-profitable only includes browsers except IE. For IE to work as well you have to get commercial license even as non-profitable project... I still use it because it is easy to use and well documented

Comment: what is meant by commercial license? we are planning to use kango for non -commercial purpose so we need to pay `$2000` for using it.

Comment: No you only need a commercial license if you intend selling the add-on or making money from it via advert insertion etc.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any more a common browser extension mechanism (plugin can't be seriously recommended).

The good news is that a big part of the work is usually plain standard and common javascript, as long as you don't touch the UI parts.

As to determine if you should program yourself or hire somebody, this isn't a question for SO.