# Framework for cross-browser toolbar development

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon, toolbar, browser-extension

I am looking for a framework with which I can create browser extensions (namely a toolbar), for all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome).

I have searched for a relevant solution, but none which I found were what I need:

1. CrossRider - no good since it can't be self-hosted. The same would apply to companies like Conduit, and nearly all other solutions I've encountered.
2. Kango - this does look exactly like what I need, but the license is too expensive IMHO.

Does anyone know a framework which will allow development - using js & html - of a cross-browser toolbar?

Comment: I see two persons who added this to favorites but haven't upvoted. I encourage you to do so (unless you don't have upvote privileges), it doesn't hurt, really.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913123/cross-browser-extensions-api?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it myself but I remember a colleague of mine talking about [firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) a while ago.

Comment: FireBreath is for developing plugins, [not extensions](http://npapi.com/extensions).