# How to send message from content script to panel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, messaging, firefox-addon-sdk, porting

I got some problems with the messaging among the main.js, page-mod's content script and panel's content script in my firefox addon.I transfer the chrome extension code to firefox addon.

1. What is the order of these js files loaded? I try to figure
   out with console,but the log is refreshed.
2. I have transfer the chrome specific API to firefox addon API,but I can't sure the other native message js code should change.Now,I will show you the example.
   in `main.js`:

   ```
   var pmworker = []
   var pagemod = PageMod({
      include: ['*'],
      contentScriptWhen: 'start',
      contentScriptFile: [data.url('pm-content.js')],
      onAttach: function(worker) {
          worker.port.on('message',
          function(data) {
               switch (data.type) {
               case 'some type':
                  do something;
                  break;
               }
           });
           worker.on('detach',function() {
              detachWorker(this, pmworker);
           });
           pmworker.push(worker);
       }
   });   


   var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
     width: 322,
     height: 427,
     contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
     include:["http://*/*","https://*/*"]
   });   

   panel.on('message', function(messagedata) {
       switch(messagedata.type) {
         case 'some type':
           panel.port.emit("something");
           break;
       } 
    });
   ```

in `pm-content.js`:

```
var sendInfoToFrame = function(){
    var frameWindow = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow;
    var infoMsg = {type:"some type",content:something};
    frameWindow.postMessage(infoMsg, "*");
}
```

in the `panel.html`'s `head` include a `panel.js` with `script` tag:

```
function addParentListener(){
    window.addEventListener("message",function (e) {
        var message=e.data;
        if(message.type="some type"){
            //do something
        }
    },false);
}
```

so the message can be sent from `pm-content.js` to `panel.js` with `contentWindow.postMessage`? And the `panel.js` use `window.addListener` to receive the msg(these example code from `panel.js` and `pm-content.js` is copied from chrome extension code,and I don't change it)?

Conversely,How is the msg sent from `panel.js` to content script ? I also copy the same code from chrome and I don't whether it's right. The example code is:
in the panel.js:

```
function sendSomeMessage(value){
    var message = {type : "sometp",value: value};
    window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
}
```

and the receive code in the `pm-content.js`:

```
   function addMessageListener() {
    window.addEventListener("message",function(e) {
            var message = e.data;
            if (message.type == null) {
                    return;
            }
            var msgType = message.type;
            switch (msgType) {
            case "sometp":
                    //do something
            }
    }, false);
   }
```

I run the code and I get lots of errors.So should I change these messaging code and How ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the order of these js files loaded? I try to figure out with console,but the log is refreshed.

Use the Network Panel instead of the console

> I have transfer the chrome specific API to firefox addon API,but I can't sure the other native message js code should change.Now,I will show you the example. in main.js:

Use or analyze an existing tool, as in a similar question:

[Cross-Browser Extensions API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913123/cross-browser-extensions-api)