# Cross browser extension development framewok

Tags: frameworks, cross-browser, development-environment

I was evaluating the development of a cross browser extension (supported browsers IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox): I was looking for a cross-browser development framework, in order to avoid the code duplication and to fasten the building process.
I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913123/cross-browser-extensions-api), and I visited the suggested websites: every company seems to have stopped working on the product.
I read this [article](http://www.amaslo.com/2016/01/crossrider-not-recommended-for-cross-browser-extensions.html) too, whose conclusion seems to dissuade developer from the building of a cross browser extension.
So, I have a few questions: 
- Does anyone of you recommend a cross browser extension development framework, which is suitable for the purpose I described above? 
- Is there a reason why the above frameworks are not maintained anymore?
- Does anyone discovered a more efficient way to pursue the same aim without developing a browser extension?

Thanks so much,
Daniele

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I not tested it yet, but [Firefox WebExtensions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/cross-browser-extensions-available-now-in-firefox/) seems to be best choice. Yes, you must [make some changes to code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities), but usually it is not that bad.

> WebExtensions APIs are inspired by the existing Google Chrome
>   extension APIs, and are supported by Opera, Firefox, and Microsoft
>   Edge. We’re working to standardize these existing APIs as well as
>   proposing new ones! Our goal is to make extensions as easy to share
>   between browsers as the pages they browse, and powerful enough to let
>   people customize their browsers to match their needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: the problem is that I have to create an Internet Explorer 11 extension too. WebExtensions does not support it, right?

Comment: @DanieleMilani Hmm... I think that it will be complicated to have support to all modern browser and internet explorer, but I don't know of any other way to do good cross browser extensions that WebExtensions.

Comment: Thanks: so you suggest to build two different extensions, one for IE and one for the other browsers (the last one realized using WebExtensions)? A further question: do you recommend any tool I can use to fasten the IE extensions development? Thanks so much, Daniele

Comment: @DanieleMilani Probably yes. Main problem of IE is that you must develop plugins with C++/C# instead of JavaScript, so it is harder to develop and this extensions will be compatible only with IE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions/5740004#5740004 Sorry. I don't know of any tool for developing IE extensions. Also I would to note that Firefox probably will support only WebExtensions in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Plasmo](https://github.com/PlasmoHQ/plasmo). It's by their words:

> The Plasmo Framework is a battery-packed browser extension SDK made by hackers for hackers. Build your product and stop worrying about config files and the odd peculiarities of building browser extensions.

Even it's in early development stage, it has features like:

- First-class React and TypeScript support
- Hot reload
- Support of .env files
- Automated deployment